# yii2 Dropdown not showing completely in actionColumn in gridview

Tags: php, css, gridview, yii2, kartik-v

In my yii2 project, Im using a Dropdown to display the actions in actionColumn for my gridview. the problem is that the dropdown does display entirely when the number of data rows is less that 3 or 4 (just the enough space to show all the actions)-See picture-1. But when there's enough rows and space the dropdown showup correctly (see picture-2).

I tried to fix it with CSS by changing the value of z-index but no luck.
If anyone would help I would be so grateful.

**Picture-1**

[image: Picture-1]

Here's my code :

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:10%;'],
    'header'=>'Actions',
    'template' => '{all}',
    'buttons' => [
    'all' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
        return ButtonDropdown::widget([
            'encodeLabel' => false, // if you're going to use html on the button label
            'label' => 'Choisir',                         
            'dropdown' => [
                'encodeLabels' => false, // if you're going to use html on the items' labels
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'label' => \Yii::t('yii', '<i class="icon-search4"></i> Voir'),
                        'url' => ['view', 'id' => $key],
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => \Yii::t('yii', '<i class="icon-pencil5"></i> Modifier'),
                        'url' => ['update', 'id' => $key],
                        'visible' => true,  
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => \Yii::t('yii', '<i class="icon-list"></i> Valider'),
                        'url' => ['validate', 'id' => $key],
                        'visible' => true,  // if you want to hide an item based on a condition, use this
                    ],
                    /*[
                        'label' => \Yii::t('yii', "<i class='icon-city'></i> Voir le vendeurAgence"),
                        'url' => ['annonces', 'agence_id' => $model->vendor_id],
                        'visible' => true,  // if you want to hide an item based on a condition, use this
                    ],*/                                  
                    [
                        'label' => \Yii::t('yii', '<i class="icon-bin"></i> Supprimer'),
                        'linkOptions' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'method' => 'post',
                                'confirm' => \Yii::t('yii', 'Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette vente ?'),
                            ],
                        ],
                        'url' => ['delete', 'id' => $key],
                        'visible' => true,   // same as above
                    ],
                ],
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'dropdown-menu-right', // right dropdown
                ],
            ],
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'btn-default',
                'style' => 'padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;',   // btn-success, btn-info, et cetera
            ],
            'split' => true,    // if you want a split button
        ]);
    },
    ],
```

**Picture-2**

[image: Picture-2]

Comment: its hard to guess until there is a live link to the problem cuz the problem is more related to css issue

Comment: I tried hard with css for both the dropdwon and the containing divs, and I got nothing..

Comment: still if you could provide with a working example that would be helpful

Comment: You want a link to the webpage that contains the gridview ?

Comment: yeah a link to the page on web where **you are having this issue** would helpful to troubleshoot

Comment: Sorry, that's prod, I can't afford that for now, I should copy it and upload it to a test server with test data..

Comment: yeah if you can replicate the issue and upload it somewhere else that would also be ok

Comment: I'll let you know when I do

Comment: Is your dropdown handled by `Choisir`? Make sure the parent class `.dropdown` has `position: relative;`

Comment: Well, if it's <<relative>> the height of the row expands, for now it's absolute